# How to group array but not create new object?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array (size=21)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '20' (length=2)
  3 => string '19' (length=2)
  4 => string '14' (length=2)
  5 => string '13' (length=2)
  6 => string '' (length=0)
  7 => null
  8 => null
  9 => string '20' (length=2)
  10 => null
  11 => string '10' (length=2)
  12 => string '' (length=0)
  13 => null
  14 => string '13' (length=2)
  15 => null
  16 => string '' (length=0)
  17 => null
  18 => null
  19 => string '' (length=0)
  20 => string '20' (length=2)
```

And I would like to create a new array from this array by grouping rows with the same string. e.g.

**2 => string '20' (length=2)** with **20 => string '20' (length=2)** and with **9 => string '20' (length=2)**

and

**5 => string '13' (length=2)** with **5 => string '13' (length=2)**

etc.

and order the new created array rows based on how many times the string occures there.

Order need to be DESC from the most occurrences to the last like a classic top something chart (The most present strings are first and the least are low)

So, the modified array will look like this:

```
 array (size=21)
      0 => string '20' (length=2)
      1 => string '13' (length=2)
      ...
```

I also need somehow to handle null results e.g. **17 => null** to be not incorporated at all in the final array modified result.

Comment: looks like an assignment, try yourself and ask if any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
// Filter the "null results" first
$myarray = array_filter($myarray, create_function('$arg', '
    return !is_null($arg);
'));

$occurrences = array_count_values($myarray);
// EDIT: arsort preserves the key => value correlation
arsort($occurrences, SORT_NUMERIC);

var_dump(array_keys($occurrences));
```

Comment: Thanks, it outputs this: array (size=8)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 2
  3 => int 3
  4 => int 4
  5 => int 5
  6 => int 6
  7 => int 7

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Please hang on a moment, I'll fix the issue and update.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it groups them coorectly, but I need to remain the values e.g. "20", "13" etc. and reorder based on occurrences. How to do that?

Comment: Edited it. Should be ok, now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$result = array_count_values($a);
arsort($result);

$result = array_keys($result);
```